# Splitting a dataframe by columns

Tags: r

I want to split my dataframe by columns. Sounds trivial, but i didnt really succeed so far.
Here is what i have come up with:

```
SG <- data.frame(num = 1:26, let = letters, LET = LETTERS)
SG <- lapply(SG, function(x) split(x, colnames(SG)))
str(SG)

List of 3
 $ num:List of 3
 $ let:List of 3
 $ LET:List of 3
```

I have successfully converted my dataframe into a list of lists. But i would like to have a list of dataframes, preserving the rowname info from `SG`, and each one of them containing one column of the initial dataframe. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your desired output?  A list of three data.frames with one column?

Comment: yes, exactly. i want a list of dataframes containing one column of the original dataframe each, so i can later do "list2env"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, row names are preserved. It returns a list of data frames:

```
SG <- lapply(SG, data.frame)

str(SG)
List of 3
 $ num:'data.frame':    26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X..i..: int [1:26] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ let:'data.frame':    26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X..i..: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ LET:'data.frame':    26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X..i..: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! very easy, however, the colnames are not preserved.

Comment: You're welcome. This will retrieve that colnames: `for (i in 1:length(SG)) colnames(SG[[i]]) <- names(SG)[i]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
lapply(colnames(SG), function(x) SG[,x,drop=F])
```

which returns an object with the structure

```
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ num: int [1:26] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   26 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ LET: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

In this case we are just subsetting. `split()` for data.frames is better when you want to separate the rows, not columns, into different groups.

Comment: Thank you! for some reasons, list2env(SG, envir=.GlobalEnv) is not working here?