# Split a Data Frame by every second column

Tags: r, split

I have a 'data.frame':  260 obs. of  342 variables. As you can see a very wide data set indeed. I need to wrangle into 171 separate data frames each with 260 observations and 2 variables Index and Price. Every 2 columns is its own data frame. The name of the data frame is the preceding column( i.e. the index ). Below is an example of how my column names look for my wide data frame

```
INDEX1 | Price.1 | INDEX2 | Price.2 | INDEX3 | Price.3 ..........
```

I tried using the apply in the below link 
[Splitting a dataframe by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217812/splitting-a-dataframe-by-columns) however it split each variable into its own data frame.

Comment: Why do need so many separate data frames?

Comment: Price column is fixed or is there several price columns?

Comment: You have one dataset of 3 variables (index,price,id) I would have thought. There's no need to split. Regardless, you basically have a "reshape wide to long" problem. `names(df) <- sub("([^0-9.])(\\d)", "\\1.\\2", names(df));
reshape(df, direction="long", sep=".", varying=TRUE, timevar=NULL)` for one method to fix it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen perhaps you are right I may not need all those data frames. I may be able to wrangle the data better before I bring it into R. I will adjust the question at some point today.

Comment: @mannym You can stick with one data frame and then _access_ that data frame in group-of-two columns as needed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would I go about this doing this by sub setting with []?

Comment: You can subset a data frame `df` by name by using something like `df[, c("col1", "col2")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toy example for 3 variable-combinations:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(sapply((1:6),function (x) rnorm(10,1,1))))
colnames(df) <- paste0(rep(c("Price","Index"),3),rep((1:3),each=2))

# list of separated df's
lapply((1:3),
       function(x) assign(paste0("df",x), 
                          df[,colnames(df) %in% paste0(c("Price","Index"),x)]))

# separated df's
for (i in (1:3)) {
  assign(paste0("df", i), 
         df[, colnames(df) %in% paste0(c("Price", "Index"), i)])
}
```

Comment: I tried the following code, but I don't get why it wouldn't work. `for (i in 1: ncol(df)) {
  assign(paste0("df", i), df[, (i:i+1)], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`.

Comment: for (i in seq(1,ncol(df),2)) { assign(paste0("df", (i %/% 2) +1), df[, (i:(i+1))]) }